# Objective-c call touch on screen without user touching the screen

Tags: objective-c, uiview, touch

Im going to be using a framework that allows a iphone app to control my app on iPad. When i add it im going to make the joystick move a image of a mouse, and when the user presses the A button, i want to make the device think the user is touching at that point. Is there any way to do this?

Example: I place a button on the ipad screen at 0,0 with height and width of 100. then mouse is at point 50,50 and when the user presses and holds A, that button is held down, and when user lifts up, it calls that buttons action.